# Cannot import in excel file

Tags: jquery, excel, kendo-ui, kendospreadsheet

I'm using the kendo spreadsheet plugin to open an excel file. However I can't import the excel file at all in IE, but it works in chrome. I'm getting error in this line: `this.toolbar.action({command:"OpenCommand",options:{file:e.target.files[0]}})`in kendo js. Anyone know how to solve this? Below is my code:

```
 $("#spreadsheet").kendoSpreadsheet({
    excelImport: function(e) {
    e.promise
    .progress(function(e) {
         console.log(kendo.format("{0:P} complete", e.progress));
    })
    .done(function() {
         alert("Export completed!");
    });
 }

});
```

Comment: Try to convert excel data to Base64 String. I have done var buffer = new Buffer(fContents, 'base64'); in nodejs and it works.